# Каким способом можно вывести количество подключений к серверу(игровому)?

Tags: linux, сервер, gameserver

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать  мониторинг игрового сервера?
Требуется вывести количество активных подключений (т.е игроков) на сервере и статус сервера off/on. Вопрос достаточно простой, но как обратиться к серверу и запросить эти данные я не знаю.

Comment: Так для начала хоть хостинг свой скажите... И сервер. Что за сервер?

Comment: Если самописный, то нужно его код менять.

Comment: Допустим, что обычный KVM Linux Ubuntu. Сама суть реализации нужна.

Comment: Меня интересует не ОС, а именно программа - сервер и хостинг. Не зная этого дать ответ невозможно.

Comment: Количество игроков на вашем сервере не является какой - то переменной, которая хранит ОС.

Comment: Обыкновенный игровой сервер, разницы нет cs:go,sa:mp,minecraft  и тд.

Comment: разница есть, причём огромная. У каждого сервера разная система работы и универсального варианта нет.

Comment: Меня конкретно интересует как в общем делают эти колонки мониторинга. Как запрашиваются данные о статусе сервера и количестве подключений в принципе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71176/discussion-between-user263096-and-spark).

Comment: Т.е есть готовые серверные команды в зависимости от , скажем , игровой платформы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объяснил в [этом чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71176/discussion-between-user263096-and-spark). 
P. S.: Не знаю, удаляются ли чаты или нет со временем.